# Android Client app cannot connect to Java PC Server - No Route to Host Error

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I'm building an app for Android that will communicate with a PC and exchange data.  I've been mainly going through several examples in learning how to make apps and how to use Java sockets.  One example that I have been trying to get to work is:

http://lakjeewa.blogspot.com/2014/05/simple-android-client-server-application.html

I've modified a few things from the code above (names of variables and key press functions) and when I use the IP Address: 10.0.2.2, and run the app in an emulator and the server on a desktop connected to a private network, the app and server works.  I'm able to send a message from the app on the emulator to the server and the server receives it.

However when I run the server on a laptop and the client app on an android phone that are both wirelessly connected to another private network, I get an error in the android studio console saying "**No route to host**."  I went into my laptops command terminal and was able to ping my phone.  And I've replaced the area of the code with the correct IPv4 Address and socket.  I've also connected my laptop and phone to another wireless network and still cannot establish a connection.

What could be the issue?  Is there something I must specify in the code to enable connections?  Or do I have to do something with the network or hardware devices to establish the connection?

Please note:
Code for activity, manifest and layout is basically the same as shown in the link, except for variable name changes and I removed the function: `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT 2**
Below is my source code for the android client:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // reference to the text field
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the send button

        // Button press event listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                messsage = textField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
                textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                client = new Socket("192.168.1.37", 4444); // connect to the server
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                client.close(); // closing the connection

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                /* If I try to send a toast notification my app crashes
                String text = "Could not connect";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast notify = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                notify.show();*/
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                /*String text = "Could not connect";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast notify = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                notify.show();*/
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Source code for the server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author alexc
 */
public class JavaServer {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");
                int count = 0;
        while (count < 1000) {
                    count++;
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                System.out.println(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }
                serverSocket.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You only have to change the ip address. So what did you use?

Comment: `I get an error in the android studio console`. Console? I would think an exception in the logcat.

Comment: @greenapps Yeah sorry for the incorrect terminology but yeah the logcat showed an exception which said "No route to host." I'm used to calling IDE output areas, consoles.  And yeah I changed the IP Address to the IP Address of my laptop on the network in this line of code (line 57 of the android client sample code) on the android client: 'client = new Socket(myIP, 4444);' myIP is an IPv4 address like 192.xxx.x.x.

Comment: Adapt your code so the user is informed about the exceptions. Then switch of the firewall.

Comment: you may install some android console (terminal) app and try to ping to the server ip.. check if you get the same error

Comment: @greenapps so I switched off my firewall and I still was unable to make a connection.  So I did what Carlos suggested and tried to ping my server ip and to my shock my phone is unable to ping my server.  I tried pinging my server from a different computer and it didn't work even with the firewall and antivirus turned off.  I think there could be some issues with the network router I am connected to.  Getting a wireless router on Monday and creating my own private LAN (not connected to the internet) to do some tests.  I posted my code in the OP if it will help

Comment: That ICMP message comes from a router, and it means that the router has no route to the network, or even a default route that it can use when if doesn't have a specific route for the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Hey y'all so I got my friend's router which is a Linksys E1000 Wireless-N router from Cisco and tested my android app and Java server and it works.  Don't know what the exact configurations are but this what I did:

1. Enable DHCP on the router, otherwise you will have to set static IP Addresses on your PC and Android Phone
2. Make sure your PC and Android Phone are enabled to be discoverable on the network.  I just remembered on my PC when I connected to this router, it asked me do I want to be able to be discovered on the network
3. Turn off firewall (and antivirus), or keep the port open you want all your connections for your android app to go through.

If you still have issues, here are some general troubleshooting tips (as whatever devices you use will vary):

- If you are not getting assigned IP addresses for your PC or android Phone and DHCP is enabled, try resetting the router (turning it off and on again; or full system reset)
- For windows, open command prompt and type `ipconfig` and find your IPv4 address.  Make sure that you type the address in correctly.  Then in the commmand prompt type `ping 'android phone's IP Address'` For example:

  ping 192.168.1.121

If you get a response that means your phone is on the network.

- For Android phones, download this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.streamsoft.pingtools&hl=en

Then try to ping the IPv4 address you found for `ipconfig` if your phone can ping it, then you are all good.  If you can't ping it, try turning off the firewall and antivirus.

Anyway thank you all for the help and suggestions.  Hope these suggestions help.